# Excel VBA disable opening of workbook while trying to save it

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro:

```
Sub btnToCsv()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ds, Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ds = Sheet1
    
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set Ws = Wb.ActiveSheet
    
    Ds.Range("A2:J200000").Copy Ws.Range("A1")        
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyCSV.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    MsgBox "Saved Successfully!"        
    Wb.Close
End Sub
```

The above macro gets activated from a button on an existing sheet. At the following line, a new workbook opens up on computer screen which might look a litte awkward for my non technical users. That temporary workbook closes at end of `Sub`.

```
Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
```

How do I disable or hide the temporary workbook from opening on screen?

Comment: `Wb.Visible = False`

Comment: Or disable screen updating during the macro